# How to read a json graph with networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I got a json file which is converted to a dict with theses keys:

```
graph = {'directed': True, 'multigraph': False, 'nodes': [{...}], 
         'graph': [], 'adjacency': [[{}]]}
```

How can I convert it for using it with `networkx`?

I've already tried `networkx.readwrite.json_graph.adjacency_data(graph)` but it ends with an error.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use [`adjacency_graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.adjacency_graph.html#networkx.readwrite.json_graph.adjacency_graph) instead of [`adjacency_data`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.adjacency_data.html#networkx.readwrite.json_graph.adjacency_data):

```
H = json_graph.adjacency_graph(graph)
```

Comment: the method returning an error is `json_graph.adjacency_data` and not `json_graph.adjacency_graph`